# How to remove 'u'(unicode) from all the values in a column in a DataFrame?

Tags: unicode, pandas, ipython

How does one remove `'u'(unicode)` from all the values in a column in a `DataFrame`?

```
table.place.unique()


array([u'Newyork', u'Chicago', u'San Francisco'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: It's a good thing to have Unicode strings in your program! When you write to a file you can specify an encoding, e.g. `table.to_csv('/path/file.csv',encoding='utf8')`. The default encoding is ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([u'c%s'%i for i in range(11,21)], columns=["c"])
>>> df
     c
0  c11
1  c12
2  c13
3  c14
4  c15
5  c16
6  c17
7  c18
8  c19
9  c20
>>> df['c'].values
array([u'c11', u'c12', u'c13', u'c14', u'c15', u'c16', u'c17', u'c18',
       u'c19', u'c20'], dtype=object)
>>> df['c'].astype(str).values
array(['c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19', 'c20'], dtype=object)
>>>
```